# 1.How can I compare 2 chars 2.How can I increase the size of my dynamic array using realloc and print the information it has

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays, realloc, strcmp

I am writing a program where if the user chooses "2" the program will add a new student record and if he chooses "4" then it will compare his surname with all the other surnames, it will find everyone that has the same surname and print their school information. The problems are the following:

When the user selects "2" my program actually shows all the prompts that are needed and you can input all the information however when I try to print it just gives me 0   0 0.000000 .When it should have given me 2(id) B(name) b(surname) 1(semester) 4(grade).

When the user selects "4" it reads the surname but when it goes to compare it with the others to see if it exists or not it just crashes.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student{
int id;
char name[50];
char surname[50];
int semester;
float grade;
}student;


int main()
{
    int x,std,i;
    x=0;
    int car=0;
    int flag=1;
    struct student *ptr = NULL;
    
    
    while (x!=8)
    {
        printf("\n1. Initialize student list\n2. Add a student record\n3. Delete a student record\n4. Display a student record by student surname\n5. Display students passed\n6. Display students failed\n7. Display all student records\n8. Exit");
        printf("\nYour choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);

        if (x==1)
        {
            printf("How many new students? ");
            scanf("%d",&std);
            ptr = (student*)malloc(std*sizeof(student));
            
            for(i = 0; i < std; i++){
               printf("Enter detail of student #%d\n", (i + 1));
               ptr[i].id=i+1;
               printf("Enter first name: ");
               scanf("%s", ptr[i].name);
               printf("Enter last name: ");
               scanf("%s", ptr[i].surname);
               printf("Enter semester: ");
               scanf("%d", &ptr[i].semester);
               printf("Enter grade: ");
               scanf("%f", &ptr[i].grade);
            }
            

        }
    
        else if (x==2)
        {
            ptr=realloc(ptr,100* sizeof(student));
            std=std+1;
            ptr[std].id=std+1;
            printf("Enter first name: ");
            scanf("%s", ptr[std].name);
            printf("Enter last name: ");
            scanf("%s", ptr[std].surname);
            printf("Enter semester: ");
            scanf("%d", &ptr[std].semester);
            printf("Enter grade: ");
            scanf("%f", &ptr[std].grade);
            flag=0;

        }
        else if (x==3)
        {
            /* code */
        }
        else if (x==4)
        {
            printf("Give the surname: ");
            const char *sur;
            scanf("%s", sur);
            for (i = 0; i < std; i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(sur, ptr[i].surname)==0){
                    printf("%d ", ptr[i].id);
                    printf("%s ", ptr[i].name);
               printf("%s ", ptr[i].surname);
               printf("%d ", ptr[i].semester);
               printf("%f ", ptr[i].grade);
               printf("\n");
               car=1;
               

                }
            }
            if (car=0)
            {
                printf("That surname does not exist");
            }
         
     }
```

I may have missed a "{" but this is only part of my code

```
else if (x==7)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < std; i++){
               printf("%d ", ptr[i].id);
               printf("%s ", ptr[i].name);
               printf("%s ", ptr[i].surname);
               printf("%d ", ptr[i].semester);
               printf("%f ", ptr[i].grade);
               printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For when the user chooses "2" everything goes well until its time to print so i tried increasing std by 1 two times.One when the program goes to option "2" and another time when it goes back to main. It didnt do anything so i returned it to how it was in the beginning.

For when the user chooses "4" I tried going with strcmp but it would just throw errors because of sur. I had it written as char sur. After I wrote it as const char *sur it stopped throwing errors but it would just crash when it went to compare it with the other.

Comment: `const char *sur; scanf("%s", sur);` is a recipe fro *undefined behaviour*. You're reading  string data into lord-knows-what because `sur` has no determinate address, much less one that is known to be large enough to hold the user's string.

Comment: Just a side advice, don't use `std` for naming objects or variables. I can imagine some people getting confused (as I initially did) with C++ `std` namespace.

Comment: If you trace the value of `std`, you'll see there's a _hole_ between using step 1 then step 2. This _hole_ will be uninitialised data leading to UB... (Or, just run the program and go straight to step 2... The 0th element will be the _hole_ in the array...)

Comment: `if (car=0)` is not testing the value of the variable. It is assigning the value 0...

Comment: You have: `int x,std,i; x=0; int car=0;` — it is generally considered better to define one variable per line, and to include the initializer with the definition: `int x = 0; int std; int i; int car = 0;`.  You could defer defining `i` until the `for` loops where it is used.  That improves the locality of reference — minimizing the scope at which a variable is accessible.